# How to define a where clause in a onetomany class definition

Tags: java, persistence

I am new to Java Persistence etc 
I have a one to many relation defined and it works, but I cannot define the where clause in the many entity. 
For instance, my search is returning a list of orders and a collection of order items per order.
But, how do I apply a where clause in the LineItem entity class e.g.
The native SQL will look like this (roughly)

```
SELECT Orders.OrderNumber, LineItems.Quantity, LineItems.Description
FROM Orders, LineItems WHERE Orders.OrderID = LineItems.OrderID
AND LineItems.Description IN ('XXX1', 'XXXXX2','XXXX3')`
AND LineItems.Quantity = 5
```

I dont know how to define the :

```
AND LineItems.Description IN ('XXX1', 'XXXXX2','XXXX3')
AND LineItems.Quantity = 5
```

in the LineItems class.
Please Help.

Comment: What do you mean by "a where clause in the LineItem entity class"? A where clause is defined in a query, not in an entity.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a workaround than an answer to your question, but it may be the only way to do it: Create a [NamedQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html) that restricts the results the way you want and use the NamedQuery instead.  [Here's a tutorial on how to do that.](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named)

[The answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082162/jpa-hibernate-conditionally-onetomany-relationship) imply that my suggestion is the only way to accomplish what you need.  Those answers are Hibernate specific.